# importing jit from numba raise an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jit, numba

So I'm trying to import `jit` from the `numba` library but the import produces an OSError and says that a specific module couldn't be found.
I tried to uninstall and reinstall numba, but it didn't change anything and I have no other idea to solve the issue.

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\user65\Logiciels\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\ffi.py", line 42, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(_lib_dir, _lib_name))
  File "D:\Users\user65\Logiciels\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 350, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Le module spécifié est introuvable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/user65/HypotheseDecoupageReseau/CalculInfluence.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numba import jit
  File "D:\Users\user65\Logiciels\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\numba\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import config, errors, runtests, types
  File "D:\Users\user65\Logiciels\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\numba\config.py", line 11, in <module>
    import llvmlite.binding as ll
  File "D:\Users\user65\Logiciels\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .dylib import *
  File "D:\Users\user65\Logiciels\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\dylib.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "D:\Users\user65\Logiciels\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\ffi.py", line 47, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(_lib_name)
  File "D:\Users\user65\Logiciels\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 350, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Le module spécifié est introuvable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

As said in [this page](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/315) you are not alone. This is the problem of the version `3.4.4`

You have some options:

1. Try upgrading and see that the problem solves.
2. Aside from that people saying It's due to `script\python.bat` and `python.exe` interfering.
   `python.bat` is currently calling `ptpython` when it sees it, which has not the same syntax.
   You may try `pip uninstall ptpython` and see if it helps.
3. You may also copy the current `python.bat` as `winpython.bat`, and keep `python.bat` calling only python:

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0env_for_icons.bat"
cd/D "%WINPYWORKDIR%"
rem backward compatibility for python.exe
"%WINPYDIR%\python.exe"  %*
```

4. After following the above solutions, `llvmlite` error part should be solved by now. You should have `Visual Studio 2015` installed for other error parts to go away.
   Although you can instead install `vc_redist.x86.exe` alone from [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-visual-c) and dont install the whole VS2015. Follow [here](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/235) for more information.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reference ! I followed the steps but i might have gone one wrong cause it's not working. I tried replacing `winpython.bat` by `python.bat` and replace the `python.bat` by the code you wrote and it didn't work. So i tried to put that code in winpython instead and still not working. Could you carify a bit and tell me where i am mistaken ? thank you very much anyway !

Comment: First try to upgrade and if it did not solve, install the `vc_redist` and it should work.

Comment: I am not administrator of my computer as i am at work so i cannot install vc_redist as asked and i can only install the binary version of the library found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numba) and the version haven't been updated since my last installation.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using a compatible version of Python.

In my case I had to remove Python and downgrade to a previous version